# Why using <Null> after showDialog?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I'm rendering an `AlertDialog` inside `showDialog` to display when error thrown from provider file. But that didn't work first time( Seems like stuck in `catchError` block, didn't execute future of `catchError`), Then I told to add `<Null>` after `showDialog`. That worked But How, What is changed, what it means?

Here is the code

```
if (_editedProduct.id == null) {
    Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
        .addProduct(_editedProduct)
        .catchError((error) {
      return showDialog<Null>(     //Here is that Null I didn't understand
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('ERROR'),
              content: Text('Error Occured'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text('I GOT IT'),
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    }).then((_) {
      print('THEN');
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
  } else {
    Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
        .updateProduct(_editedProduct.id, _editedProduct);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

Nb: `isLoading` true shows a `circluarProgressIndicator()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Official Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html)

> Returns a Future that resolves to the value (if any) that was passed to Navigator.pop when the dialog was closed.

The place where you sent `Null` indicates the type of data the Future will return.

By using `Null` you are indicating that the Future won't return any data, this tell your program not to wait for the possible value that might be returned.

Suppose in your dialog user has to pick 2 numbers and you want the picked number to be returned to the place where you called the `showDialog()` function then you'll use `int` instead of `Null`.

Something like

```
showDialog<int>(...)
```